# Examining local variables up the stack

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

When debugging with `Eclipse` and `gcc`, if I select a frame in the stack, different then the most deep one, the following happens. In `Expressions`, I can type any local variable and I get the value.

However, using the `Console` window to talk to `gcc`, I get the following

```
p coeff_table
No symbol "coeff_table" in current context.
```

How do I tell `gcc` to reference this local variable?

Comment: And `coeff_table` is a local variable in your current stack frame?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, `coeff_table` is a local variable in a stack frame, that is not the deepest, but I have clicked on it in the "Debug" window (i.e. the call stack window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to select the stack frame containing the `coeff_table` local variable.

The typical command to change the frame is the `frame`/`f` command.  Print a backtrace (`bt` command) to get the number of the frame and then select that frame.  When you have selected the right frame, you should be able to print the value of the `coeff_table` local variable.

To use the [GDB sample session](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session) as an example, suppose that the backtrace is:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  set_quotes (lq=0x34c78 "", rq=0x34c88 "")
    at input.c:530
#1  0x6344 in m4_changequote (argc=3, argv=0x33c70)
    at builtin.c:882
#2  0x8174 in expand_macro (sym=0x33320) at macro.c:242
#3  0x7a88 in expand_token (obs=0x0, t=209696, td=0xf7fffa30)
    at macro.c:71
#4  0x79dc in expand_input () at macro.c:40
#5  0x2930 in main (argc=0, argv=0xf7fffb20) at m4.c:195
```

And suppose that the `coeff_table` variable is a local variable of the `expand_token` function.  You would need to select frame #3:

```
(gdb) f 3
```

See [8.4 Selecting a Frame](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Selection.html#Selection)

Comment: Or you can do "bt full" if you prefer to list locals in all frames.